# Updating images in UIImageView during execution?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an interface which contains several UIImageView components on a view and i would like to update the animation images in run-time.

The main idea is to change the animation images into a thread with a delay of 2 seconds. The code below works fine. However, when i introduce a sleep time (with the commented NSThread sleepForTime); it no longer works. I am sure there is a logical explanation but i cannot identify it.

It's important to note that the animation is already running with another set of animated images.
Any help or tip is more than welcome :)

```
        dispatch_async(allowToTouchThread, ^{

            //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
                int randomnReward =  0;
                WizzReward* currentReward = [rewardListForPages objectAtIndex:randomnReward];
                WizzAnimalModel* animalModel = [gameLevelManager getAnimalModelByCategoryId: [currentReward getAnimalId]];

                NSMutableArray* expressionsForAnimals = [animalModel getArrayForClosedEyesFaceExpression];
                float animationDuration = [animalModel getStandardRewardAnimationDuration];
                pageContentViewController.imagesArrayFileLevel1  = expressionsForAnimals;
                pageContentViewController.animationLevel1Duration = animationDuration;
            }

});
```

Comment: How about a repeating timer, then change the images on the main thread?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing your `dispatch_async` to a `dispatch_after` and set a delay of 2 seconds:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    int randomnReward =  0;
    WizzReward* currentReward = [rewardListForPages objectAtIndex:randomnReward];
    WizzAnimalModel* animalModel = [gameLevelManager getAnimalModelByCategoryId: [currentReward getAnimalId]];

    NSMutableArray* expressionsForAnimals = [animalModel getArrayForClosedEyesFaceExpression];
    float animationDuration = [animalModel getStandardRewardAnimationDuration];
    pageContentViewController.imagesArrayFileLevel1  = expressionsForAnimals;
    pageContentViewController.animationLevel1Duration = animationDuration;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it gets the same result. It's interesting that it works fine without a timer whatever its form (NSThread, thread timer , etc...) but as soon as a timer is introduced the animation is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the animated images without any timer, could be done directly by modifying the array of images.

However, changing the same animated images with a timer, needed 3 steps:

- first the modification of the image arrays
- second the actual re-association of the UIView AnimationImages to the modified array of images;
- and finally startAnimating the UIView eventhough it hasn't been stopped beforehand

The source code below now works fine with a timer:

```
WizzReward* currentReward = [rewardListForPages objectAtIndex:0];
WizzAnimalModel* animalModel = [gameLevelManager getAnimalModelByCategoryId: [currentReward getAnimalId]];
NSMutableArray* expressionsForAnimals = [animalModel getArrayForClosedEyesFaceExpression];



pageContentViewController.imagesArrayFileLevel1 = expressionsForAnimals;
pageContentViewController.reward1CurrentPage.animationImages = pageContentViewController.imagesArrayFileLevel1;
[pageContentViewController.reward1CurrentPage startAnimating];
```

I did find neither "time vs no-timer difference"information  in the literature nor actual reason why it should be done like that; but it works every time. Hope it helps anyone who runs into the same problem.